# Как сформировать математическую формулу?

Tags: математика, интерполяция

Мне нужна формула, чтобы при

```
x=1 -> y=1  
x=2 -> y=5  
x=3 -> y=9  
x=4 -> y=13
x=5 -> y=17  
x=6 -> y=21  
x=7 -> y=25  
x=8 -> y=29
x=9 -> y=33  
x=10 -> y=37  
x=11 -> y=41  
x=12 -> y=45
x=13 -> y=49  
x=14 -> y=53  
x=15 -> y=57  
    ...
```

Подскажите, какая формула описывает эти данные?

Comment: Ага, раз исправили... Ну, скажем, кубический многочлен вас устроит?

Comment: сори, изменил...)

Answer (score 3):

Устроит?

```
y(x) = 1+(4+(x-3)(x-2)/6)(x-1)
```

Comment: спасибо большое) не подскажите, каким образом можно научиться, имею ввиду какая часть математике изучает именно это?

Comment: См. интерполяционный полином :)

Comment: ok, спасибо еще раз)

Comment: я извиняюсь, оказывается неправильно выложил пример, изменил, пожалуйста подскажите какая формула будет в этом случае, заранее спасибо

Comment: Нарисуйте график, или посчитайте разности между соседними значениями y - и все станет просто очевидным...

Answer (score 1):

```
x=1 -> y=1    
x=2 -> y=5     4
x=3 -> y=9     4
x=4 -> y=13    4
x=5 -> y=17    4
x=6 -> y=21    4
...
```

В последнем столбце - разности меджу значением y в точке и в предыдущей точке. Так что понятно, что при вырастании x на 1 yрастет на 4 - т.е. формула

```
y = 4*x + a
```

Найти а можно из первой же точки: `1 = 4*1 + a`.

Результат:

```
y = 4*x - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все точки лежат на одной прямой, то её уравнение имеет вид

[image: Прямая по двум точкам]

Если не все точки лежат на одной прямой, то можно выбрать пару "правильных" точек на графике и применить ту же формулу.

Или применить формулы метода наименьших квадратов для прямой

[image: Формулы МНК для прямой]